# How to define collections of filepaths with forEach()

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Trying to fix repetitive action by fitting it in forEach() function. console.log providing desired results but not code itself. Could you explain why it isnt working?

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
const cmdHandler = ["commands","automation"];
const fileSys = require("fs"); 

cmdHandler.forEach((v, y) => {
    bot.v = new Discord.Collection();
    console.log(v);

    fileSys.readdir(`./${v}/`, (error, file) => {

        if(error) console.log(error);

        let  jsfile = file.filter(f => f.split (".").pop() === "js")
        if(jsfile.length <= 0){
            console.log("Couldn't find the commands.");
            return
        }

        jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
            let props = require(`./${v}/${f}`);
            console.log(`${f} loaded.`);    
            bot.v.set(props.help.name, props);
        });  
    });
});

let fullCmd = msg.content.substr(prefixlen);
    let splitCmd = fullCmd.split(" ");
    let mainCmd = splitCmd[0];
    let args = splitCmd.slice(1);

    // Set variable for directory content called from ./commands
    let commandFile = bot.commands.get(mainCmd);
    // execute "run" section of command
    if(commandFile){ 
        commandFile.run(bot,msg,args);
```

Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this just adds an attribute `v` to bot and assigns its value.

```
bot.v = new Discord.Collection();
// bot.v has a value
```

it looks as if you are trying to use your array elements as attribute names.

```
bot[v] = new Discord.Collection();
// bot.commands assigned, ... bot.automation assigned
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It is true I am trying to create collections for commands and automation files. when I try **bot[v] = new Discord.Collection();** outputs error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: now I understand it solved my problem. Thank you Sir!